# SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable() always false in Android 11

Tags: android, android-11, android-speech-api

As the title implies, `SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable()` returns false in Android 11 and I am not sure why that is as the device (Pixel 3 XL) is equipped to recognize speech. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer#isRecognitionAvailable(android.content.Context)) doesn't indicate that it changed in API v30. The strange thing is that I still get the STT prompt successfully even if `isRecognitionAvailable` is false. Below is sample code illustrating this point. Why is the isRecognitionAvailable check always false? The code is not complete by any means but I've added the important related sections:

```
AndroidManifest.xml
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
...
```

```
MainActivity.kt
...
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) { //rationale prompt
        }
        val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
        ){ isGranted: Boolean ->
            if(isGranted) { checkSTT() }
            else { //error perms not granted
            }
        requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
    } else { checkSTT() }
}

private fun checkSTT() {
    if(SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this)) { runSTT() }
    else { runSTT() //Run anyway because isRecognitionAvailable is always false and STT works anyway?
    }
}

private fun runSTT() {
    //Yes, I know this is deprecated
    val sttIntent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
    sttIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
    sttIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.US)
    startActivityForResult(sttIntent, 1)
}
...
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured out the solution. For some reason, as of API v30, you must add the following to the Manifest file for `SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(Context)` to return true. My testing found that it only works when placed outside of the `<application>` tag even though it complains that "element queries is not allowed here". Add `suppress AndroidElementNotAllowed` to remove the warning.

```
<!--suppress AndroidElementNotAllowed -->
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
    </intent>
</queries>
<application...
```

Comment: Another way to solve "AndroidElementNotAllowed' is by upgrading your project gradle version to the latest one.